# Cat command and echo

Tags: linux, concatenation, cat, echo

I'd like to concatenate the output from echo with content of a file. I've tried the following comand:

```
echo "abc" | cat 1.txt > 2.txt
```

but the `2.txt` file only contains the content from `1.txt`. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Programs like `cat` only read from standard input if they don't have any filename arguments.

Answer (score 28):

It does not work because the `cat` program in your pipe sequence was not instructed to read the `echo` program's output from standard input.

You can use `-` as a pseudo file name to indicate standard input to `cat`.
From `man cat` on an msys2 installation:

```
EXAMPLES
       cat f - g
              Output f's contents, then standard input, then g's contents.
```

So try

```
echo "abc" | cat - 1.txt > 2.txt
```

instead.

Answer (score 22):

As noted by others, your original command fails because `cat 1.txt` disregards its standard input. Either indicate that it should be its first argument (`cat - 1.txt`), or use *block redirection* to redirect `echo abc` *and* `cat 1.txt` together. To wit:

```
{ echo abc; cat 1.txt; } > 2.txt
```

Relevant excerpt from the manual ([`man bash`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html)):

> **Compound Commands**
>   A compound command is one of the following. 
>   In most cases a *list* in a command's description
>   may be separated from the rest of the command by one or more newlines,
>   and may be followed by a newline in place of a semicolon.
>
> `(`*list*`)`
>
>   *list*
>   is executed in a subshell environment (see COMMAND EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT below).
>     Variable assignments and builtin commands
>     that affect the shell's environment do not
>     remain in effect after the command completes. 
>     The return status is the exit status of list.
>
> `{` *list*`;` `}`
>
>   *list*
>   is simply executed in the current shell environment.
>   *list*
>   must be terminated with a newline or semicolon. 
>     This is known as a
>   *group command*
>   . 
>     The return status is the exit status of
>   *list*
>   . 
>     Note that unlike the metacharacters
>   **`(`**
>   and
>   **`)`**
>   ,
>   **`{`**
>   and
>   **`}`**
>   are
>   *reserved
>     words*
>   and must occur where a reserved word is permitted to be recognized. 
>     Since they do not cause a word break,
>     they must be separated from
>   *list*
>   by whitespace or another shell metacharacter.

The first option (subshell environment) has a bunch of side effects, most if not all of which are irrelevant to your scenario; however, if redirecting a bunch of commands' output is all you need, then Option #2 here (group command) is preferred.

Answer (score 10):

```
( echo "abc"; cat 1.txt ) > 2.txt
```

You piped the echo output to cat, but cat had no use for input, and ignored it.  Now the commands run one after the other, and their output is grouped (the parentheses) and directed into 2.txt.

Comment: This answer can be improved by explaining *how* it works and *why* the OP's original attempt does not work.

Comment: OK, gave it a try.

Comment: A subshell is not expressly required here, perhaps it would be better to use a group command. See my answer for more details.

Comment: Ah, but I'd never use bash.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille: While [Daniel’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1285136/354511#1285196) quotes from [```bash(1)```](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html), it describes behavior that every [POSIX-compliant](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04) shell must support.

Answer (score 3):

In any POSIX shell you could use command substitution to use `cat file` as input for `echo`:

```
echo $(cat file1.txt) "This Too"
```

In Bash you could use process substitution and use echo as another "file" for `cat`, as in:

```
cat file1.txt <(echo This Too)
```

and then pipe or redirect the output as you see fit.

Like every other answer says, cat ignores stdin if it's got a file to look at. (I do like Daniel & mvw's answers too, +1 for them)

Comment: This answer can be improved by explaining why the OP's original attempt does not work (and therefore why this is necessary instead).

Comment: The `<(command)` construction is a bash extension. It is not POSIX, so you can't rely on it in scripts that are supposed to be executed with `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 3):

Your command `cat 1.txt` doesn't do anything with the output of `echo "abc"`.

Instead:
`(echo "abc"; cat 1.txt) > 2.txt`
will write the output of both commands into 2.txt.

Comment: This answer can be improved by explaining how the suggested alternative works.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a guess, but it looks like you have a repeatable process, which is a good candidate for an alias or a function. Aliases are usually shortcuts for invoking Bash commands, such as abbreviation, on a single input stream as its argument(s).

```
alias hg="history | grep"
```

However, in this case, a function would be more readable, since you are combining multiple, discrete (2) input streams as well as multiple bash commands. You have two arguments, the first being a string and the other a filepath. In the end, you want the result to be written to the [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) stream.

From a CLI prompt, type this:

```
# ecat()
{
echo ${1}
cat ${2}
}
```

Your function is named ecat, which is memorable.

Now you can invoke as

```
ecat "abc" 1.txt
```

To append, simply supply a different output destination to standard output:

```
ecat "abc" 1.txt >> 2.txt
```

The append redirection operator '>>' will add the output to the end of the specified file.

If you like it, then append to your ~/.bashrc file for reuse.

```
declare -f ecat >> ~/.bashrc
```

That also means you can decorate, etc., within your function definition.

It is also a good idea to protect files from being overwritten by adding this to your *[~/.bashrc file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example)* file:

```
set noclobber
```

Comment: For your function to behave properly, you should use `"$1"` and `"$2"`. In this context, the curly braces don't do any good. See [*`${name}`* doesn’t mean what you think it does …](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32210/80216#286525).

Comment: How is the `noclobber` suggestion responsive to the question at hand? (I'm also very much unconvinced that it's good advice -- modifying global behavior tends to break scripts/advice/practices built with defaults in mind).

Answer (score 0):

The following code will also work:

```
echo abc >> 1.txt && cat 1.txt > 2.txt
```

The output of  *echo abc* will be appended to 1.txt with *>>*
After that the *&&* will tell it to run the next set of commands which will *cat 1.txt* and then output it to *2.txt*. Basically, it appends the output of the first command into 1.txt and then sends the output of 1.txt into 2.txt.

If you want the abc to appear first, you can use the following code:

```
echo abc >> 2.txt && cat 1.txt >> 2.txt
```

Comment: This will (1) put `abc` at the *bottom* of `2.txt`; the question wants it at the top.   (2) ***modify*** the `1.txt` file; this is unacceptable.

Comment: Where does it say that? Ringger81 never specified where in 2.txt he wanted abc to appear. You are assuming things that the question never states.

Comment: (1) OK, you raise a valid point on #1. While the question mentions “output from echo” before “content of a file” in the text, and then puts the `echo` before the `cat` in the sample command, I suppose that it never exactly, ***explicitly**,* says that it wants the output from echo before the content of the input file. It just seems that most people interpreted it that way. (2) `1.txt` is an input file. The question doesn’t say anything about modifying `1.txt`. The fact that input files should not be modified goes without saying.

Comment: I can understand your point about not modifying the imput file. My second code will achieve the desired effect without doing so.

Comment: @NasirRiley Your second option is not equivalent to what the OP is looking for, since it will not overwrite `2.txt` if it already exists. It should be `echo abc > 2.txt && cat 1.txt >> 2.txt`.

Comment: Once again, it is important to read what the question is. It was never stated as to whether or not Ringger81 wanted to overwrite the contents of the file nor was it ever stated whether or not there was data in the file. You are assuming that such a thing is desired but there is no way for anyone to be clear on that. If he doesn't want the data in 2.txt to be overwritten then your answer would be incorrect. Ringger81 has already shown knowledge of appending data to files so the code can be modified for whichever result is desired.

Comment: Opening a file, appending to it, *closing it*, opening it again, appending to it again... why do that rather than just open it once and keep the redirection in place for both operations?

Comment: What does it matter? It's a very simple operation. You're making it seem as though it's something very taxing when it isn't.